# Как вызвать два метода по клику в Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

В разработке приложения я использую vue cli у меня есть такой код

```
<button @click="remove(idx)">Да</button>
```

Он вызывает метод

```
methods: {
    async remove(id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('removePost', id);
},}
```

но у меня есть еще один метод

```
consoleLog: function(record) {
    let windowControl = record.path[3];
    windowControl.classList.add('h');
    console.log(windowControl);
},
```

и мне его нужо также вызвать по этому-же клику

Answer (score 3):

Используйте внутри кавычек обычный синтаксис javascript:

```
<button @click="remove(idx);consoleLog(record)">Да</button>
```

либо, что гораздо более "красиво", создайте объединяющий метод, в теле которого будут выполняться два вышеуказанных, и вызывайте именно его по клику.